# Finding SVG elements with particular attributes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a portion of JavaScript in an HTML page that says:

```
function flashElements() {
    var svg = document.getElementById("mysvg").getSVGDocument();
    var all = svg.getElementsByTagName("flash");
    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (all[i].flash === "on")
        {
            all[i].setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "lime");
        }
    }
}
```

with the SVG loaded as follows:

```
<object data="alpha.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="mysvg" width="800" height="600"></object>
```

The idea is to call this on a particular trigger and, if any SVG elements have the particular attribute of "flash" then their fill attribute will change colour. Of course, the above doesn't work - it's looking for elements, not attributes. So how do I iterate through all the SVG elements, looking for anything with that particular attribute?

The SVG has:

```
<polygon points="203,20 209,32 205,32 203,28" class="trackPlain" flash="on" />
<polygon points="205,32 209,32 217,48 213,48" class="trackPlain" flash="off" />
```

Actually all I want to do is flash the elements (on/off) but of course IE doesn't support animations.

Comment: Just a note: it's bad authoring practice to use non-prefixed custom attributes, you should use either `custom:flash="on"` or `data-flash="on"` to avoid clashing with future svg specs. The 'custom' prefix is just an example, it can be whatever you define it as (see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/).

Comment: Ah ok, I did wonder! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very efficient, but I imagine you could do something like this:

```
var allElements = svg.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];

    if(element.getAttribute("myAttr") === "on") {
        element.setAttribute("fill", "lime");
    }    
}
```

Your other option is to do a tree-traversal.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. I tried putting 10,000 rects onto the screen and alternating their fill every 750ms. On Firefox is racked up 10% processor power; on IE 6%; and on both the effect was simultaneous rather than a kind of wipe effect I was expecting. But I won't be changing that many elements at once!

Comment: If a more efficient variation would be var `allElements = svg.querySelectorAll("[data-flash='on']");` and then loop without comparing the attribute.

Comment: @Duopixel Good point. I was in a bit of a hurry when I answered and didn't think to use XPath.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use CSS selectors, that avoids changing a ton of attributes and the effect should be the same.

```
<style>
  .trackplain[flash="on"] { fill: lime; }
</style>
```

**Update:** to be clear, the above should be placed inside the svg document.

Comment: That's a new one on me - I really ought to learn CSS properly! Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

other answer using Typescript & inskscape svg :

```
this.mySvg = svg.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
let myDom = this.svg.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(let i=0; i < myDom.length; i++) {
      let label = myDom[i].getAttribute('inkscape:label');
      let style = myDom[i].getAttribute('style');
      if (label && style) {
           myDom[i].addEventListener("click", () => this.onClick(myDom[i], style));
      }
    }
```